# Sum / Counting items in a column that match 3 criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, formula

Thank you ahead of time for anyone who can help me with this, I think I am close, but it still isn't working.

I have a simple sheet activity reporting sheet that I am asking staff to complete over the upcoming year - It has 5 columns:

1. Column A: Date  -In format (4/4/2013 13:30:00)
2. Column B: Title -In format (text string)
3. Column C: Attendance -In format (Numbers)V
4. Column D: Vol led  - In format (text string)
5. Column E: Staff Led - In format (text string)

Using this data I am 90 % positive that I can aggregate on a different summary sheet that contains some static data like months (in the B column) to aggregate on. I am having trouble configuring the criteria in the filters though to cause the correct output to either sum or count .

- **Quantity of events ed by either staff or vol, if neither box is checked the event should not be counted)** Right now I am trying this but it is not working

*=SUM(FILTER('Hostel Activities'!A:A,MONTH('Hostel Activities'!A:A)=$B3, NOT(AND(ISBLANK('Hostel Activities'!D:D),ISBLANK('Hostel Activities'!E:E)))*

- **Total number of attendance in a month for activities led by staff or volunteers** Right now I am trying this but it is not working

*=SUM(FILTER('Hostel Activities'!A:A,MONTH('Hostel Activities'!A:A)=$B3, NOT(AND(ISBLANK('Hostel Activities'!D:D),ISBLANK('Hostel Activities'!E:E)))*

- THIE WORKS! ## Heading ##**Total number of volunteer led activities in a month for activities** Right now I am using this and it IS working

*=COUNT(FILTER('Hostel Activities'!A:A,month('Hostel Activities'!A:A)=B3,not(isblank('Hostel Activities'!E:E))))*

Thank you for any assistance and/or guidance

Danny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have figured out a method that works by making some adjustments in the formulas and the source data.

Basically

**IN THE SOURCE REPORTING DATA**:

I combined columns D and E into the same column and added data validation so the coordinator has to enter if the activity is led by staff,volunteer, or neither.

**IN THE MONTHLY AGGREGATION REPORT**:

To count the number of activities led by either staff or volunteers I used this :

=COUNT(FILTER('Hostel Activities'!A:A,month('Hostel Activities'!A:A)=B3,'Hostel Activities'!D:D="Staff"))+E3

*E3 is the count of volunteer led activities which is found using this formula:

=COUNT(FILTER('Hostel Activities'!A:A,month('Hostel Activities'!A:A)=B3,'Hostel Activities'!D:D="Volunteer"))

Adding up the number of participants in activities run by either staff or volunteers was a little more difficult, but I was able to do it by adding up 2 unique equations. I would prefer using an OR statement in the filter criteria, but I just couldn't get that to work. This is how I was able to make it happen:

=SUM(FILTER('Hostel Activities'!C:C,month('Hostel Activities'!A:A)=B3,'Hostel Activities'!D:D="Staff")) + SUM(FILTER('Hostel Activities'!C:C,month('Hostel Activities'!A:A)=B3,'Hostel Activities'!D:D="Volunteer"))

Thank you all for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see with your first two formulas is that you're calling `SUM` on your `FILTER` result. But the `FILTER` is returning the column `A`, which are dates. So, your basically summing dates, which will surely not yield the result you're looking for. Why are you not using `COUNT`, as you did on your last formula?

Second, the first two formulas you pasted are identical, how do you expect them to return different results?

It seems that for the first two want to sum an OR condition. You can do this two ways (that I can think of now). The simpler to understand is just to sum two `COUNT(FILTER(...` formulas, one for each criteria, e.g.

```
=COUNT(FILTER('Hostel Activities'!A:A,month('Hostel Activities'!A:A)=B3,not(isblank('Hostel Activities'!D:D)))) + B6
```

Assuming that on `B6` is the other `COUNT` formula (the 3rd one, that already works).

Another option would be to use an `OR` function as criteria for the `FILTER`. Like this:

```
=COUNT(FILTER('Hostel Activities'!A:A,month('Hostel Activities'!A:A)=B3, OR(NOT(ISBLANK('Hostel Activities'!E:E)), NOT(ISBLANK('Hostel Activities1!D:D))) ))
```